# Load data into Ext.data.Store with function on init in ExtJS MVC

Tags: extjs, store

I need to fill Store data on init with finction like:

```
Ext.define('Vcs.store.Years', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['year'],
    data: this.getYears(),
    getYears: function() {
        var data = []
            date = new Date
            thisYear = date.getFullYear();
        for(var i = thisYear - 100; i <= thisYear; i++) {
            data.push({
            year: i,
            });
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

This code gives error: `Object [object global] has no method 'generateYears'`

Comment: Neither solution from below works in Architect: the closure gets all the whitespaces removed, thus `new Date` becomes an undefined `newDate`; and the function `me.getYears()` gets quotes, thus becoming a string `'me.getYears()'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
Ext.define('Vcs.store.Years', {  
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['year'],
    data: (function() {
        var data = [],
            date = new Date,
            thisYear = date.getFullYear();
        for(var i = thisYear - 100; i <= thisYear; i++) {
            data.push({
            year: i
            });
        }
        return data;
    })()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the scoping of your `this` is wrong. you'll have to populate the data in the constructor:

```
constructor: function() {
    var me = this;
    Ext.apply(me, {
       data: me.getYears()
    });
    me.callParent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither solution suggested so far works in Sencha Architect: the closure gets all the whitespaces removed, thus `new Date` becomes an undefined `newDate`; and the function `me.getYears()` gets quotes, thus becoming a string `'me.getYears()'`.

So for those who use Sencha Architect here's a version that should be used. I simply used the .add() method on store's "load" event.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'MyStore',
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'year',
                    type: 'int'
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                load: {
                    fn: me.onStoreLoad,
                    scope: me
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    },

    onStoreLoad: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
        store.add(function() {
            var data = [];
            var date = new Date();
            var thisYear = date.getFullYear();

            for (var i = thisYear - 100; i <= thisYear; i++) {
                var obj = { year:i };
                data.push(obj);
            }

            return data;
        }());
    }

});
```